# Access Datalist label with JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datalist

I have a datalist generated from the back end. From the client side I need to access a label in the datalist with Jquery or Javascript. Here is the client side that's generated:

```
<table id="wmsBody_dlstItems" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2" style="text-align:center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                <span id="wmsBody_dlstItems_lblItemBoxID_0" class="txtPick3">4883658</span><br />
                    <span id="wmsBody_dlstItems_lblfull_item_number_0" class="txtPick2">37UPC341890NC</span><br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td><td>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2" style="text-align:center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                <span id="wmsBody_dlstItems_lblItemBoxID_1" class="txtPick3">5043328</span><br />
                    <span id="wmsBody_dlstItems_lblfull_item_number_1" class="txtPick2">37WVNL70blk</span><br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td><td>
</tr>
```

How can I access via JavaScript or JQuery the value stored in the label lblItemBoxID. There are 2 values here, 4883658 and 5043328. Thanks for your help ... Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest of all Would be is to use the `class .txtPick3`

Or you can write up jQuery code to get this ..

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/6dHWF/1/)

```
​var labels = $('table table')​.find('span:eq(0)') ;

$.each(labels, function(i){
   alert($(labels[i]).text()); 
});
```

Check the [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/yeSXR/) here

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused here and I didn't explain myself well. I understand the looping labels, however, I want to access just one label value. For instance, I want to access the lblfull_item_number value of (37UPC341890NC) in the same TD as the lblItemBoxID value of 4883658. More clearly maybe ... I'm scanning a barcode JQuery captures, the barcode is the 4883658 value. When I scan that barcode (4883658) lets say I want to alert the lblfull_item_number value of 37UPC341890NC.

Comment: I have added an updated fiddle that finds the item number based on the bar code given to it.. Check the above code.. Let me know if this is what you are looking for..

Answer (score 0):

Your best option, given your generated HTML, is to [select by class](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
$('.txtPick3')
```

if you want to iterate through the elements and get the values, you should do something like this:

```
$('.txtPick3').each(function(index, elem){
    var myValue = $(elem).text();
    //now do something with the found value
})
```

Alternatively to [selection by class](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), you can also, given your HTML, select by your element ID pattern, using the ["Attribute Starts With" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('span[id^="wmsBody_dlstItems_lblItemBoxID_"]')
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused here and I didn't explain myself well. I understand the looping labels, however, I want to access just one label value. For instance, I want to access the lblfull_item_number value of (37UPC341890NC) in the same TD as the lblItemBoxID value of 4883658. More clearly maybe ... I'm scanning a barcode JQuery captures, the barcode is the 4883658 value. When I scan that barcode (4883658) lets say I want to alert the lblfull_item_number value of 37UPC341890NC.